# How many permutations with no adjacent characters?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say I have `ABCDEF`. Then, there are $6!$ permutations of reordering that string. Now, I would like to only deal with the permutations in which there are no adjacent characters. That means, I want to look at all the permutations that satisfy these constraints:

- B is not next to A or C
- C is not next to B or D
- D is not next to C or E
- E is not next to D or F

However, I am not sure where to even start with dividing out the ones I don't need.

Comment: Ue inclusion/exclusion principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of such permutations is related with the [OEIS sequence A002464](http://oeis.org/A002464). By using inclusion/exclusion principle we can count the number of permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that any two permuted elements are not consecutive numbers:
$$n!+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\sum_{k=1}^i\binom{i-1}{i-k}\binom{n-i}{k}2^k(n-i)!$$
A proof of this formula can be found in [D. P. Robbins, "The probability that neighbors remain neighbors after random rearrangements", Amer. Math. Monthly 87 (1980), 122-124](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321990?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

In your case $n=6$ and the formula yields
$$720-1200+768-228+32-2=90.$$

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this equation working with a relative small length sequence, perhaps of length 4? By a brute force method, I have concluded that there are only 2 such permutations that exist: 3142 and 2413. But I would like to see this proven using that equation.

Comment: For $n=4$ the formula gives $24-36+16-2=2$.

Comment: Two ways to compute the value of this formula for $n\ge1$ using either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX may be found in [this posting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339056/5001).